# Error on executing command (linux) : $ docker ps -a

Tags: docker

After installing Docker on Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

- I started docker :`systemctl start docker`
- `sudo docker run hello-world`
- finally listed containers : `$ docker ps -a`

RESULT : `An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json?all=1: EOF`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION :

- update ubuntu
- shutdown and restart ubuntu

Error disappear